# Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "/assets/google-logo.png")

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml, dart-null-safety

I am trying to load an image in flutter, but it's showing error

output

[image: output]

file Directory

[image: files]

pubspec.yaml

```yaml
    # The following section is specific to Flutter.
    flutter:
      uses-material-design: true
      assets:
        - assets/
```

Code

```dart
     const SizedBox( 
         child: Image(
         image: AssetImage(
           '/assets/google_logo.png',
         ),
     ))
```

error

```
    Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "/assets/google_logo.png")
    Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#fbe16(), name: 
    "/assets/google_logo.png", scale: 1)
```

Comment: try hot reload app and add path into pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

You need to access like this : `assets/assets/google_logo.png`

Answer (score 0):

except this(*/assets/assets/google_logo.png*), you can try this **assets/assets/google_logo.png** without slash at front side